# How can WorkManager be used for widget updating?

Tags: android, android-service, android-widget, android-workmanager

Android Oreo (8.0) makes it very hard to update widgets ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179256/how-to-properly-update-a-widget-in-android-8-0-oreo-api-26),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204609/oreo-alarm-is-not-fired-when-application-is-not-running),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706921/android-o-can-we-make-a-clock-widget)) 
 either by clicking a button (PendingIntent) or automatically updating every X minutes. I am looking into how I could use the new [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for this.

I was able to use if for another task not related to widgets, and it works well. However, I can't find any example (or even a quick outline) on how to use it with widgets to be able to update them periodically (let's say every 5 minutes) and also update them when a RemoteView is clicked. BTW, this requires downloading a file from the internet and displaying contents in RemoteViews.

Has anyone tried it and how did it work out? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WorkManager` which scheduler your `Workers` using `JobScheduler`. There is nothing special about a `Widget` in Android O which makes things different (from `WorkManager`s perspective).

Comment: Also, the minimum interval for PeriodicWork is 15 minutes (same as JobScheduler Periodic Job). If you need it every 30 seconds — consider using OneTimeWork and schedule it again when the work is done.